# Unable to start webcam via Cheese: cluttervideosink missing

Tags: webcam, cheese

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on my HP DM4 laptop. Also, I have `gstreamer1.0-clutter` installed. Still getting the error

```
One or more needed GStreamer elements are missing: cluttervideosink
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After reading this redhat bugzilla : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1047389

it came to the part where the dev team suggested this:

```
rm ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.x86_64.bin
```

this worked for me... :)

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick search with 'aptitude search videosink' and found:

```
gstreamer0.10-videosink
gstreamer0.10-videosink:i386
gstreamer1.0-videosink
gstreamer1.0-videosink:i386
```

Does installing any of these help?

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-videosink
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-videosink
```

I also searched for 'cluttervideo' and 'clutter-video' but found nothing.

Comment: BTW, googling for clutter-video will remove "video" from the search results.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. `E: Package has no installation candidate` for both. Thanks anyways

Comment: Hmm.. There are some packages like 'gstreamer-plugins-good'  'gstreamer-plugins-bad' 'gstreamer-plugins-ugly'. Maybe one of those?

Answer (score 0):

I launched `sushi` from command line and it registers some mimetypes and voila... `cheese` works.

Answer (score 0):

I found `GStreamer1.0-alsa`  ( Gstreamer plugin for alsa ) in the Ubuntu Software Center.

After installing it, the problem is solved for me.
(on Linux Mint 17.3 KDE)