# Unable to delete a folder, it keeps recreating itself

Tags: directory, delete

Ubuntu 15.10.

I was attempting to get the webcam application "Cheese" to work. Some of the proposed solutions involved deleting a folder in my home directory:  `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0`.

However, whenever I delete that folder, it immediately recreates itself.

Why is this happening? How do I determine what is responsible for this happening?

Comment: Because you have software running that depends on it.

Comment: That directory is for user settings. deleting it sort of forces it to reset to defaults and is unlikely to fix your problem.

Comment: I agree: there is NO reason to delete that.

Answer (score 0):

The folder belongs to [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-general.html) package:

> GStreamer is a development framework for creating applications like
>   media players, video editors, streaming media broadcasters and so on

It is likely that whichever video/audio player you are using is relying on that framework, hence it's creating the config directory for it. Deleting it is somewhat pointless, as it will reappear.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.  I still have my original question though:  How do I determine what is responsible for this happening?  

Regarding the statement that deleting it is pointless:  The reason I thought to delete it was due to the answer given here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/461045/unable-to-start-webcam-via-cheese-cluttervideosink-missing  which said to delete that folder in order to make Cheese work.  Are you saying that suggested solution is incorrect?  (Even if it is a poor solution, still:  Why were others able to delete this directory, and I cannot?)

Comment: @dln949 that answer suggests to remove `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0` but you are trying to remove `~/.config/gstreamer-1.0` .  I don't know how true that solution is, but sometimes it does help to remove such folders. HAve you posted actual question about your issue with cheese yet ?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my original question which had a typo in it.  I meant to type that I am trying to remove ~./cache/gstreamer-1.0.  

Very embarrassed.  Oh well, thanks for pointing that out.  

Yes, I did post about the Cheese problem, everyone suggested a solution that involved removing ~./cache/gstreamer-1.0, that's how I found out that I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can lead to complications and confusion, but there is a method that often works to keep certain files and directories from being created. Put something else in its place.

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0 && ln -sf gstreamer-1.0 ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0
```

That should create a symlink at `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0` which cannot be resolved. A reasonably robust application may complain, but will continue without using that directory. A brittle application will have an aneurysm and crash.

Regarding your webcam application, deleting the contents of that folder clears the gstreamer cache. That is probably sufficient to eliminate that as a cause of your problem. gstreamer will store its cache data *somewhere*, so preventing it from using its default location would not change *how* gstreamer functions.

Your princess is in another castle.